# Raspberry Pi 4 and Google Assistant with Bluetooth Mic and Speaker

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, assistant

I need some help to make it work...
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 on Raspbian and a JBL Go2 Bluetooth that is speaker and mic...
The assistant is working properly (voice commands are executed) but google has no voice...so no OUTPUT... (i cant 
That means microphone working ok on console but no speaker...

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

also

with

speaker-test -t wav

i got no audio output...cant hear anything...but i get no errors or something like that

BUT on

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay /home/pi/recording.wav

Playing WAVE '/home/pi/recording.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Stereo

i can hear the recording i have done earlier properly on terminal enviroment...

I could like to make the assisant talking... :/
On next step could like to make it handsfree...
Thanks